# Web View Orientation iOs

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using a ModalViewController to open an web view in my app.

Inside my class, i've this piece of code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"address";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];                 
    [myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

Well, in my app the interface orientation is always in portrait mode. But, when i start the web view, a video will show up, and i need to change my interface to every kind of orientations. 
Observation: I don't want to change on the class that i am running the modal view controller. I just want to change the orientation inside my video.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking; what exactly is your question?

Comment: I would like to change my ModalView's interface to every kind of orientation. My app is just able to be on the Portrait Orientation. Is that possible?